# Deploying a build with NPM on Visual Studio Online

Tags: gruntjs, npm, bower, azure-devops

I have a Visual Studio Project which consist of an Azure Website.

This website is quite simple at the moment, it consists of an Angular App, embedded in this application.

How I'm trying to automate the deployments of this Project. Visual Studio Online offers a very nice build integration, it all wires it up automatically, I commit to `master` and lo and behold, 60 seconds it is online.

How the thing is, locally I use NPM to install Bower & Grunt. Bower is needed for Angular, ngRoute,  .... Grunt is used to copy the 'master' files of the previously mentioned packages to a specific folder inside the project to ensure I only see (e.g.) `angular.js`, `angular-route.js`, ...

How this works like a charm locally, `npm install`, `bower install`, `grunt copy_master_files`,  and I can run & test my app.

How do I weave in this 'behavior' on my continuous deployment? Is this supported? How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of very recently VSO now supports scripted builds which allows you to set up a taskrunner build and deployment. The previous way of having XAML build definitions is now discouraged as Microsoft is heavily shepherding us towards using Gulp and Grunt for builds (a very good direction, IMHO).

Comment: Having worked much more with the scripted build lately, be aware that the shared hosted controllers are virgin controllers and set up your environment fresh for every build. This means that if you have a lot of npm and/or bower packages you need to have at build-time, all those dependencies get installed then. This appears to have greatly increased the amount of broken builds, and it seems almost arbitrary nowadays when a build completes or fails. We are considering hosting our own build controller or use a Jenkins implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy fix for this. If you want this you need to deploy a custom server, and attach it as a build machine to Visual Studio Online, and install NPM & Git on it.

Answer (score 1):

A custom server is not currently necessary.  Try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicktrog/archive/2015/03/05/adding-gulp-to-visual-studio-online-builds.aspx